# Limiting number of threads for actor pool to 1

Tags: multithreading, scala, threadpool

In one of my actors react method I output the thread pool by doing:

```
val scalaThreadSet = asScalaSet(Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet());
scalaThreadSet.foreach(element => Console.println("Thread=" + element + ",state=" + 
                    element.getState()))
```

I see a bunch of threads:

```
Thread=Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6,5,main],state=WAITING
Thread=Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system],state=RUNNABLE
Thread=Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-10,5,main],state=RUNNABLE
Thread=Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13,5,main],state=WAITING
Thread=Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7,5,main],state=WAITING
Thread=Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9,5,main],state=WAITING
Thread=Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-14,5,main],state=WAITING
```

I wish to reduce the size of thread pool to one and only see one thread, so I pass in:

So I pass in:

```
-Dactors.maxPoolSize=1
```

as a VM argument.

My expectation is I should now only see one thread but I still see loads.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

Try running the VM with

```
-Dactors.corePoolSize=1
```

**Explanation**

The `ForkJoinScheduler`, which is the default scheduler for most OSes running Java 1.6 or later, uses a `DrainableForkJoinPool` under to covers which, as far as I can tell, ignores the `maxPoolSize` property. See the [`makeNewPool`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/42f34f61cefc8be17d13149703abc3e2547989ad/src/actors/scala/actors/scheduler/ForkJoinScheduler.scala#L40) method of the `ForkJoinScheduler` and the [constructor](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/42f34f61cefc8be17d13149703abc3e2547989ad/src/actors/scala/actors/scheduler/DrainableForkJoinPool.scala) for `DrainableForkJoinPool`.